# Python - Populate excel fields with incrementing time

Tags: python, excel, datetime

Full disclosure, I'm not a programmer but can attempt to write a little bit of code with some help from the forums.
I'm trying to use python to manipulate an excel file I work with.
I have an spreadsheet with five columns. In Column B is a time field (hh:mm:ss).
Not every cell in this column is populated but in the case where there is a time entered, I need to be able to increase the time by one hour in each subsequent cell until it hits another cell that contains a time already in there and then repeat the process over for that entry..
Hope that made sense. In the attached picture is a sample of the data and this would be the desired output.

> B20 : 13:00:00
>
> B26 : 17:00:00
>
> B28 : 19:00:00
>
> B30 - 32 : 10:00, 11:00, 12:00

[Excel example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TQw3z.png)

This is what I've cobbled together but it's not working and I'm completely lost in it now.

```
# Iterate over all rows in the worksheet
for row in worksheet.iter_rows(min_row=2):
    # Get the value of the cell in column B for the current row
    cell_value = row[1].value

    # Check if the cell is not empty
    if cell_value is not None:
        # Convert the value of the cell to a string
        if isinstance(cell_value, datetime.time):
            cell_value = str(cell_value)
        cell_value = datetime.datetime.strptime(cell_value, '%H:%M:%S').time()

        # Get the index of the current row
        row_index = row[0].row

        # Iterate over the rows below the current row
        for i in range(row_index, worksheet.max_row + 1):
            # Get the value of the cell in column B for the current row
            next_cell_value = worksheet.cell(row=i, column=2).value

            # Check if the cell is empty
            if next_cell_value == '' or next_cell_value is None:
                # Set the value of the cell to the updated datetime object
                worksheet.cell(row=i, column=2).value = cell_value.strftime('%H:%M:%S')
            else:
                # Convert the value of the cell to a string
                if isinstance(next_cell_value, datetime.time):
                    next_cell_value = str(next_cell_value)
                next_cell_value = datetime.datetime.strptime(next_cell_value, '%H:%M:%S').time()

                # Add 1 hour to the datetime object
                next_cell_value = (datetime.datetime.combine(datetime.date.today(), next_cell_value) + datetime.timedelta(hours=1)).time()

                # Set the value of the cell to the updated datetime object
                worksheet.cell(row=i, column=2).value = next_cell_value.strftime('%H:%M:%S')
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You forgot to post your attempt to solve this problem.

Comment: Ooops, have just done that now. Thanks.. Been a while since I posted anything to stackoverflow

Comment: Can you be more specific than "it's not working"?

Comment: You should only need 1 loop: go from top to bottom, filling each empty cell (the cell above it, if it didn't start out filled, will have been filled by a previous iteration).

Comment: The cell's get populated but not with the times I was expecting and it's overwriting the cells that do already have times in them.  My head's a bit melted with it so might leave it for a bit and come back and look at it again in a day or two. Just wanted to check if it was possible and if it's in the right direction.

Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

something like this?

```py
from openpyxl import Workbook
from openpyxl import load_workbook
from datetime import datetime, timedelta, date
wb = load_workbook(filename="worksheet.xlsx")
worksheet = wb['Sheet1']
```

```py
for i in range(3, worksheet.max_row+1):
    cell_val = worksheet.cell(row=i, column=2).value
    if cell_val == None:
        prev_cell = worksheet.cell(row=i-1, column=2).value
        curr_cell = (datetime.combine(date.today(), prev_cell) + timedelta(hours=1)).time()
        worksheet.cell(row=i, column=2).value = curr_cell
```

```py
wb.save('foobar.xlsx')
```

In your example every day starts at *09:00:00*, so I guess your (and my) script wouldn't work if the first cell of that day is blank since it will fill in the last time + 1 from the previous day. But in your example every first cell of the day is filled in so hopefully that's not a problem.

This approach avoids the `double` `loop` with `O(n^2)` complexity, now it just runs in the number of rows.

Tested it [here](https://prnt.sc/cN0OqMnJ7twG) and seemed to work fine.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Awe dude, this works perfectly. Talk about me over engineering things!! Thanks so much, this really is going to save hours of work.

Answer (score 0):

```
# Import openpyxl 
import openpyxl
import datetime
  
# Open the spreadsheet 
workbook = openpyxl.load_workbook("yourfile.xlsx") 
  
# Get the first sheet 
worksheet = workbook.worksheets[0] 


# Iterate over all rows in the worksheet
for i, row in enumerate(worksheet.iter_rows(min_row=2),1):
    # Get the value of the cell in column B for the current row
    cell_value = row[1].value

    # Check if the cell is not empty
    if cell_value is not None:
        # Convert the value of the cell to a string
        if isinstance(cell_value, datetime.time):
            cell_value = str(cell_value)
        cell_value = datetime.datetime.strptime(cell_value, '%H:%M:%S')
        
        # adds 1 hour to your cell
        next_cell_value = (cell_value + datetime.timedelta(hours=1)).time()
        
        #add the value of the next cell
        worksheet.cell(row=i+1, column=2).value = next_cell_value

workbook.save("youroutput.xlsx") #saving to see the output, not necessary for the operations.
```

Ok your 2nd loop was not necessary. If you look at the operations you are repeating your operations a lot because for each row, the second loop runs the operations for each row once again.
I've simplified by adding an enumeration to get the index so you could spot the next cell by adding 1 to the current position.

However, this is not the way I would have used from the ground up. I think you could improve on your code by using pandas which 1) makes scripting this kind of operation faster, 2) is vectorize, therefore increases speed on huge datasets.
Here is how I would have proceeded

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_excel("schedule_test_python.xlsx")

# I'm working on the presumption that "Scheduled Start of Activities as start time" is you column's name.
df["Scheduled Start of Activities as start time"] = pd.to_datetime(df["Scheduled Start of Activities as start time"], format='%H:%M:%S') + pd.DateOffset(hours=1) # treats the dates in the column as time then adds 1 hour
df["Scheduled Start of Activities as start time"] = df["Scheduled Start of Activities as start time"].dt.strftime('%H:%M:%S') # convert the column to the desired format

df.to_excel("schedule_test_python_output.xlsx", index=False)
```

I hope this helps you solve your issue.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion too. Previous one works as intended but might play around with this later.